# jQuery add and remove HTML elements with nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two buttons add and remove which add and remove divs(which contain other divs) but, if I want to remove a row I can remove only the last row(div), so I thought to add some "remove buttons" at the end of each row(div).
The problem is that I did that but I can only remove  the first row for only one time and I can't remove the other rows.

HTML CODE:

```
  <form action='' method='post'>

    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2'> <h4>Manufacturing_part_no</h4></div>
        <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <h4>Type</h4></div>
        <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2'><h4>Description</h4> </div>
        <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <h4>Value</h4></div>
        <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <h4>Voltage</h4></div>
        <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <h4>Power</h4></div>
        <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <h4>Percent.%</h4></div>
        <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'><h4>Quantity</h4> </div>        
        <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <h4>Rack_no</h4></div> 
        <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <h4>Proj. Name</h4></div>     
    </div>

      <div id='forma' >      
          <div class='row row1'>            
            <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='manufacturing_part_no1'></div>
            <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='type1'></div>
            <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='description1'></div>
            <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='value1'></div>
            <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='voltage1'></div>
            <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='power1'></div>
            <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='percentage1'></div>
            <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='quantity1'></div>            
            <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='rack_no1'></div>
            <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-block button-remove' name='btn1' value='1'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></div>
            <br>
          </div>
     </div>

      <div id='shto_heq' class=''>
      <hr>
        <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                 <button id='shto' class='btn btn-primary btn-block' type='button'>Add Row <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">  
                 <button id='heq' class='btn btn-danger btn-block' type='button'>Remove Row <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3"> 
                 <input type="text" id="numberofrows" name="maxrows" class="form-control" value="1" style="display:none;">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3"> 
                    <div id="numrirrjeshtave"></div>
                 </div>
       </div> 
      </div>



      <div id='butoni_submit' class=''>
      <hr>
        <button id='butoni' class='btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg' name='submit' type='submit'>Submit The Data <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true'></button>
      </div>

    </form>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
     <script>
     //this is where I add and remove rows, but only from the end.
     var1=1;var2=var1+1;

    $("#shto").click(function(){
        $('.row'+var1).after("<div class='row row"+var2+" hapesirandermjetrow'><div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='manufacturing_part_no"+var2+"'></div> <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='type"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='description"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='value"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='voltage"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='power"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='percentage"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='quantity"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='rack_no"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-block button-remove' name='btn"+var2+"' value='"+var2+"'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></div><br></div>");
        var2=var2+1;var1=var1=var1+1;
        $('#numrirrjeshtave').html("<button id='numrirrjeshtave' class='btn btn-default btn-block' type='button'>Number of Rows is: "+var1+"</button>");
        $('#numberofrows').val(var1);
    });
    $("#heq").click(function(){
        $('.row'+var1).remove();
        var2=var2-1;var1=var1=var1-1;
        $('#numrirrjeshtave').html("<button id='numrirrjeshtave' class='btn btn-default btn-block' type='button'>Number of Rows is: "+var1+"</button>");
        $('#numberofrows').val(var1);
    });




    </script>


<script>
// This is where i want to remove a specific row.
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var3=$(".button-remove").click().val();
    $(".button-remove").click(function(){
      $(this).closest('.row').remove();

    });

    });

</script>
```

Screenshoot:

[image: ScreenShoot]

Comment: Could you create a fiddle ? That will be easy to check and get us back to you soon :)

Comment: #Vigneswaran Marimuthu 
http://jsfiddle.net/alban_kaperi/bfcwpcmu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***JS***

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var3=$(".button-remove").click().val();
        $(document).on("click",".button-remove",function(){
          $(this).closest('.row').remove();

        });

        });
```

> Click event wasn't placed for The button to make it work just use the above code

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/15vyqLpb/10/)

Comment: What would you recommend for overwritting the classes of the div's and input names below the deleted row, e.g if i delete row4 i want the row5 and the others that are below row4 to be reduced by -1.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is after removing the first row ..there is no `row0` class aailable to append the code hence you check here if the div with class `.row0` is available or not.

```
var1=1;var2=var1+1;

    $("#shto").click(function(){
        if($('.row'+var1).is(":visible"))
           $('.row'+var1).after("<div class='row row"+var2+" hapesirandermjetrow'><div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='manufacturing_part_no"+var2+"'></div> <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='type"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='description"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='value"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='voltage"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='power"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='percentage"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='quantity"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='rack_no"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-block button-remove' name='btn"+var2+"' value='"+var2+"'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></div><br></div>");
        else
         $('#forma').append("<div class='row row"+var2+" hapesirandermjetrow'><div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='manufacturing_part_no"+var2+"'></div> <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='type"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='description"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='value"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='voltage"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='power"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='percentage"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='quantity"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <input type='text' class='form-control' name='rack_no"+var2+"'></div><div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-block button-remove' name='btn"+var2+"' value='"+var2+"'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></div><br></div>");
        var2=var2+1;var1=var1=var1+1;
        $('#numrirrjeshtave').html("<button id='numrirrjeshtave' class='btn btn-default btn-block' type='button'>Number of Rows is: "+var1+"</button>");
        $('#numberofrows').val(var1);
    });
    $("#heq").click(function(){
        $('.row'+var1).remove();
        var2=var2-1;var1=var1=var1-1;
        $('#numrirrjeshtave').html("<button id='numrirrjeshtave' class='btn btn-default btn-block' type='button'>Number of Rows is: "+var1+"</button>");
        $('#numberofrows').val(var1);
    });

// This is where i want to remove a specific row.
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var3=$(".button-remove").click().val();
    $(".button-remove").click(function(){
      $(this).closest('.row').remove();

    });

    });
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mfn3va4o/)

Comment: The idea is that i wanted the buttons that are with the class button-remove to remove their current divs, just to look better use the bootstrap css in the jsfiddle:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace your remove script with below script:

```
<script>
// This is where i want to remove a specific row.
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var3=$(".button-remove").click().val();
    //$(".button-remove").click(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.button-remove', function(){
      $(this).closest('div').parent('div').remove();
      console.log($(this).closest('div'));

    });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this there are basically two approach you can delete a row

> First is

```
    $(".button-remove").click(function(){
          $(this).parent().parent().remove();
     });
```

> Second is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var3=$(".button-remove").click().val();
    $(document).on("click",".button-remove",function(){
      $(this).closest('.row').remove();
    });
 });
```

[You can see the First demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mynameisvikram/rLahLmzq/embedded/result/)

[Second Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mynameisvikram/103trmq2/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

Do it with classnames, and use ".closest(selector)" to select the closest element (parents) matching the selector to select the "current row".

This will only work on the delete button at each row.

```
$(".button-remove").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".row").remove();
});
```

I would recommend changing the class-names to something js specific.